# How to call Screen Time at settings from my app

Tags: ios

Apps set to Screen time are strongly constrained by their behavior.
If the screen time starts while the app is running, the nature of the app causes problems in operation.

Normally, the setting screen is called by the following code, but I do not know how to call Screen Time.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(settingsURL)
```

Do you know how to do that? Or tell me if there is another way around it.

Comment: As far as I know, you're not really allowed to open Screen Time programmatically since it's considered a private API.

Comment: thank you for the advice.  I give up calling from the app